# Checking for lack of flags in bash

Tags: bash, scripting, sh, getopts

If I were to do something like this to process arguments in bash, how would I check if there were no arguments? It doesn't seem to go to the *) case, but I'd still like to put a usage statement in there somewhere.

```
while getopts 'ias' flag; do
  case "${flag}" in
    i) ifl='true' ;;
    m) afl='true' ;;
    n) sfl='true' ;;
    *) error "Invalid option ${flag}" ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: Check `OPTIND` after the loop to find the first non-option argument and see if that's the first argument? Alternatively if there aren't any legal non-option arguments just check `$#` before the loop.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks, I think checking $# sounds like it's what I need. To be clear, $# represents the number of options?

Comment: [Number of positional parameters in decimal.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the while loop, do this

```
if (( $# == 0 )); then
    echo "you must specify one of -i or -a or -s"
    exit 1
fi
```

or, after the while loop, you can do this

```
if [[ $ifl != true && $afl != true && $sfl != true ]]; then
    echo "you must specify one of -i or -a or -s"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, the second one looks most accurate to my needs, because it must have at least one of the three parameters, and if I understand correctly, the first one will not print a usage statement if there are garbage arguments.